# Checking whether a string is interleaving of two other strings

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to develop an algorithm to check whether a string s3 is interleaving of another strings s1 and s2.

Say s1="abc" and s2="abe", then possible interleavings are ababce, ababec or abcabe.
I solved it something like this :

**A: string1, B: string2 and C: interleaving of A and B**

**bool isInterLeaved(int i,int j,int k,char A[],char B[],char C[])**
{

if(!A[i] && !B[j] && !C[k])
return 1;

Note : I will do memoization to store the state, I have pasted just snippet to show my intent of the algorithm.

if(!A[i] || !B[j] || !C[k])
return 0;

bool x=0,y=0;

if(C[k]==A[i])
   x=isInterLeaved(i+1,j,k+1,A,B,C);

if(!x)
{
    if(C[k]==B[j])
    {
       y=isInterLeaved(i,j+1,k+1,A,B,C);
    }
}
return (x||y);
}

As there are a*b states, order is O(a*b) where a = Size of string A and b = size of String B.

I wanted to know if this can be done in better way. If characters in both A and B are mutually exclusive then it can be achieved in O(n) easily, but here characters can be same as well, but  still I believe there can be better ways of doing this. If anyone have any ideas do let me know.

Comment: $O(ab)$ is already far better than the naive $O(\binom{a+b}{a})$ algorithm. (But it seems that you need some memoization in addition to what you have written, before you can actually claim that $O(ab)$ complexity).

Comment: I will do memoization of states, above code is just for showing my way of solving the issue.